# Is there a way to follow the posts of individual Twitter users in Google Reader?

Tags: twitter, google-reader

I want to have feeds for people that I follow on Twitter right in my Google Reader interface, but none of the ways that I've tried to subscribe seem to work.

Answer (score 12):

For Google Reader: <sup>(thanks Jared)</sup>

1. In Google Reader, press **Add Subscription**.
2. Type in the address of the user's Twitter page (e.g. http://twitter.com/codinghorror).

For services that require an RSS feed:

1. Go to the user's Twitter page (e.g. http://twitter.com/codinghorror).
2. Find the link where it says **RSS feed of [user's] tweets** (see picture below) (e.g. `http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/5637652.rss`).
3. Add this URL to your RSS reader.

[image: Twitter page with RSS feed link highlighted]
<sub>(source: [bayimg.com](http://image.bayimg.com/manmlaacj.jpg))</sub>

Comment: You don't even need to go that far - all you need to put in the "Add subscription" box is http://www.twitter.com/username and it will find the feed automatically. [See my answer here](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1178/how-can-i-follow-someone-on-twitter-without-them-knowing/1179#1179)

Comment: If you would edit in @nhinkle's image, you answer would be truly copmlete

Comment: What about it needs editing?

Answer (score 3):

There is an RSS feed for every Twitter user. Go to twitter.com/username, and scroll down on the right side underneath followers, you will see a link for "RSS feed of username's tweets". Copy that link, and subscribe to it in Google Reader.
[alt text http://grab.by/5n0d](http://grab.by/5n0d)